# Referencing pages of articles and books

Tags: citations

I have some articles and conference papers that I am citing in my text, in my text cite I am using the page number that is related with the rest of the proceedings or the journal, even I have downloaded it or using the online version which is separate from the rest of the proceedings. I think this (Me, 2015, p.340) is confusing when the link of the document I attach will provide just the paper which probably is 4-5 pages.

So what is the appropriate page number to include in-text citing, even if the paper has the page number printed on it?

K.

Comment: Why reference a page? Sections, theorems, anything is better.

Answer (score 6):

The right page number to use is the formal page number in the larger volume, even if the actual PDF that anybody will ever download is only a few pages long.  That is because a citation is intended to give the "coordinates" of a document in an absolute and access-independent reference system.

Thus, if you are referencing an article that was published as page 374-382, then its 2nd page is page 375.  You can also refer to page [ordinally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_(linguistics)) in prose, however, in which case you make the reference point explicit and can start wherever you want, e.g., "the third page of the article", "the second page of Section III".

Comment: Thanks, that saves me some time, as I have already used the page numbers corresponding to the original numbering, and not the ones corresponding to the dowloaded file. This seemed most logical, but I had to ask since this is about a PhD thesis, so errors like that won't bear any excuse. K.

Comment: Also, the PDF will usually have the absolute page number printed on it somewhere.

Comment: @BillBarth I wish that were so... for most articles yes, but for a surprising number of articles it isn't.

Comment: @jakebeal, thus "usually", but maybe that indicated too high a frequency in your experience. Nevertheless, preprints probably won't have a correct absolute page either.